# Parallel tasks on subsets of a dask array wrapped in an xarray Dataset

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I have a large xarray.Dataset stored as a zarr. I want to perform some custom operations on it that cannot be done by just using numpy-like functions that a Dask cluster will automatically deal with. Therefore, I partition the dataset into small subsets and for each subset submit to my Dask cluster a task of the form

```
def my_task(zarr_path, subset_index):
    ds = xarray.open_zarr(zarr_path)  # this returns an xarray.Dataset containing a dask.array
    sel = ds.sel(partition_index)
    sel  = sel.load()  # I want to get the data into memory
    # then do my custom operations
    ...
```

However, I have noticed this creates a "task within a task": when a worker receives "my_task", it in turn submits tasks to the cluster to load the relevant part of the dataset. To avoid this and ensure that the full task is executed within the worker, I am submitting instead the task:

```
def my_task_2(zarr_path, subset_index):
    with dask.config.set(scheduler="threading"):
        my_task(zarr_path, subset_index)
```

Is this the best way to do this? What's the best practice for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

It's common to use methods like `apply_ufunc` or `map_blocks` to apply a function in parallel across blocks in an Xarray dataset.